# How to convert an API response to a JSON object?

Tags: python, json, api

We have an internal tool that has APIs from which we can request data. How can I convert that response to a valid JSON . I have used `head = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} and while running requests.get`

```
dc_r = "https://www.ips.com/api/v1/test"

dc = requests.get(dc_r,cookies=cookie,verify=False, headers=head)

json_dc = json.load(dc)

print json_dc
```

the output is of the following format:

```
{u'lastModifiedUser': {u'id': 1076, u'name': u'at@ips.com'}, u'organization': {u'id': 12707942, u'name': u'test.com'}, u'name': u'test-bk', u'createTime': 1563474336, u'failOpen': True}
```

How can I remove the all the occurrences of "u" from this response that preceeds each key/value pair and add double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: The `u` prefix indicates the value is a unicode string. Print defaults to using single quotes, but in memory it's still a string. Neither of those is a problem that would prevent you from using the dict in your problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I am trying to download the response from the server , edit it, and use it for a API put request.

Answer (score 3):

The returned value from `json.load(dc)` is a dictionary, which is the reason for the `u` prefix (which indicates that the strings in the dictionary are strings using the unicode charset) and the single quotes.

If your aim is to print a string you can use `json.dumps(json_dc)` to get the string representation.

Otherwise you can save a JSON file using `json.dump(dictionary, opened_file)`. `opened_file` needs to be an object with a `.write()` method.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to iterate through the API response:

```
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    data[i] = json.loads(item)
```

and turn it into a dictionary or even a list

```
data = [json.loads(d) for d in data]
```

so you can go through your payload and turn it into the payback you expect

```
[ 
  {'key': 'C#', 'value': '27779'},
  {'key': 'C++', 'value': '28415'},
  {'key': 'CSS', 'value': '6475'},
  {'key': 'HTML', 'value': '34293'},
  {'key': 'Java', 'value': '117831'},
  {'key': 'JavaScript', 'value': '205287'},
  {'key': 'Objective-C', 'value': '118096'}
 ]
```